# Xcode puts spotlight icons in the settings section and vice versa

Tags: xcode

I'm adding icons using Xcode 5 and when I select Spotlight icons XCode also put them in the Settings section, or vice versa. What's it doing, is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its not a bug. It happens because it uses same sized icons, thats why it automatically select icons.